# What takes priority in a loop: For or While?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following block of code:

```
x <- 0

while (x < 50){
  for (i in letters){
    print(i)
    x <- x + 10
  }
}
```

What is the order of operations? Does the While stop criteria apply even if there are more loops in the for loop?

I tested this and it ran through the the whole for loop, despite `x` reaching 250.

Is there a way to add a rule that says follow the while loop before the for loop?

Comment: Related, is there a way to write a for loop that `breaks` any time the criteria is broken?

Comment: Your `for` loop is *nested* inside the `while` loop; so the *inner* `for` loop finishes first, before returning to the *outer* `while` loop.

Comment: The "priority" in this case is based on *order*: the `while` loop is executed first, then `x` is increased by 10 a total of 26 times before the `while` condition is re-evaluated. If you're asking if the `while` loop can *interrupt* the internal `for` loop, the answer is "no". If you need that, then `for (i in letters) { if (x >= 50) break; print(i); x <- x + 10; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is nested inside the `while` loop. Each time the `while` loop enters an iteration, control is handed over to its loop body which is the `for` loop in this case.The `for` loop then takes control and executes its iteration. After that, the `for` loop exits its control and hands over back to `while` loop. The `while` loop kind of decides the number of times the whole for loop executes.

To `break` a for loop when the criteria is broken or with any other logic, you can use a `break` statement inside an `if` block inside the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

Since (x < 50) is true at start, no more condition checking is done until for loop is completed. The only option is to use conditional break inside for loop.

```
for (i in letters){
    if (x < 50){
        break
    }
    print(i)
    x <- x + 10

}
```

Comment: Good answer overall but I think the `if` condition is around the wrong way.